# Arrayadapter issue in android studio (android.R.layout.something did not work)

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I just follow a tutorial online and I want to write the following line of code

```
ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,countries);
```

However, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item cannot be recognized by android studio, how can i fix this? Should I import some packages?

Comment: provide some code bro so we can understand. You are using fragment or Activity?

Comment: which tutorial you follow can you provide this link?

Answer (score 0):

Here, it is reference to an **built-in XML layout** document that is **part of the Android OS**, rather than one of your own XML layouts.

There are many more layout check this [Documentation of layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html)

**The layouts are also in your SDK installation**

Path (according to your system sdk path or path you have set while downloading sdk)  :

```
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-21\data\res\layout
```

> android.R.layout.select_dialog_item cannot be recognized by android
>   studio, how can i fix this?

You may need to change refresh or try changing location of android-sdk

> Should I import some packages?

No, need just check whether all layout files are there in above path of android-sdk if they(layout) are in path of sdk than refresh(restart) your android studio.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Inform me if you have still problem @KKKK